# Creating an anonymous class from an abstract class in Scala - desugaring code

Tags: scala, playframework, specs2

Scala noob here.

I don't understand the following piece of code, taken from a Play application's integration test (Scala):

```scala
package workflows.admin

import play.api.test._

class SignInSpec extends PlaySpecification {

  "An activated user" should {
    "be able to sign in to the admin console" in new WithBrowser(webDriver = WebDriverFactory(FIREFOX)) {
      // some matchers here ...
      true
    }
  }
}
```

As far as I understand, the example creates a new anonymous class from the abstract class `WithBrowser` and instantiates it. The instance will receive the (named) constructor parameter `webDriver`.

The problem is that I don't understand what's going on here when looking into `WithBrowser`:

```scala
abstract class WithBrowser[WEBDRIVER <: WebDriver](
    val webDriver: WebDriver = WebDriverFactory(Helpers.HTMLUNIT),
    val app: Application = GuiceApplicationBuilder().build(),
    val port: Int = Helpers.testServerPort) extends Around with Scope {

  def this(
    webDriver: Class[WEBDRIVER],
    app: Application,
    port: Int) = this(WebDriverFactory(webDriver), app, port)

  implicit def implicitApp: Application = app
  implicit def implicitPort: Port = port

  lazy val browser: TestBrowser = TestBrowser(webDriver, Some("http://localhost:" + port))

  override def around[T: AsResult](t: => T): Result = {
    try {
      Helpers.running(TestServer(port, app))(AsResult.effectively(t))
    } finally {
      browser.quit()
    }
  }
}
```

I have two questions:

1. `WithBrowser` is a generic abstract class with a type parameter `WEBDRIVER`, but the type parameter is not declared in the example. Instead, the anonymous class' instance receives this information using the named constructor parameter `webDriver`. What's the missing link between the type parameter and the constructor parameter ?
2. The example declares a block of code (it just returns `true`) and this block of code is the test itself. But where does that code go in the anonymous class ? `WithBrowser` extends `Around` and overrides the `around` function, which executes the code block, but I don't understand how the generated anonymous class moves the given example code block into `around`.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Scala can infer type parameters. Since none of the passed parameters' type is somehow related to the type parameter and would thereby restrict the type to be inferred, the scala compiler will just infer it as type `Nothing`.
2. The code block would normally be the constructor of the class, but this is a special case. The `Around` class does extend the `scala.DelayedInit` interface. This will rewrite the code within the constructor to a call of the `delayedInit` function. The code that would actually be the constructor is passed as call-by-name parameter to this function. This value (actually wrapped in a `org.specs2.execute.Result.resultOrSuccess` call) is the parameter passed to the `around` function.

Imagine the `Around` class like this:

```
class Around extends DelayedInit {
  def delayedInit(f: => Unit): Unit = around(f)
  def around(f: => Unit): Unit
}
```

Let's say you will now inherit the around class:

```
class Foo extends Around {
  println("Hello World")
}
```

The above gets rewritten to this:

```
class Foo extends Around {
  delayedInit(println("Hello World"))
}
```

If my explanation was not clear enough or you want to know more implementation details:
- Here is [`Around`](https://github.com/etorreborre/specs2/blob/8305db76c5084e4b3ce5827ce23117f6fb6beee4/core/shared/src/main/scala/org/specs2/mutable/Around.scala) and the [`DelayedInit`](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~hmiller/scaladoc/library/scala/DelayedInit.html) documentation.

Comment: It's "infer," not "interfere."

Comment: Thank you, Aki and Brian. That explains it. I was not aware of DelayedInit and I‘m quite surprised about that traits‘ existence. Seems like a very awful hack to change the class initialization based on the existance of a trait in the user namespace.

Comment: DelayedInit is mainly used to implement the `App` class. This feature has actually [been](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/3563) [deprecated](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5479) for its surprising behavior with release `2.11.0`.